# Separación de filas y columnas en Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

estoy tratando de separar tal cual la imagen las filas y las columnas de esta estructura web. Solo he logrado separar las verdes con un margin-bottom: 5px; en la superior y un margin-top: 5px; en la inferior. Las demás me resultan imposibles. 
Por favor, ¿alguien podría ayudarme?
Gracias de antemano.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola user. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Tu pregunta se considera muy amplia y es motivo de cierre. Si ves [ask] verás que tienes que proveer de un ejemplo de lo que has intentado y por que no resultó. Si no sabes por donde empezar has de buscar en internet por tu cuenta. Un saludo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes ponerle un borde blanco a los divs para hacer la separación:

```css
div[class^='col-']{
  border: 5px solid white;
}
.verde{
  background-color: green;
  height: 80px;
}
.rojo {
  background-color: red;
}
.rosa{
 background-color: violet;
 height: 80px;
}
.naranja{
 background-color: orange;
 height: 80px;
}
.azul{
 background-color: blue;
 height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 verde"></div>
</div>
<div class="row rojo">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 hidden-xs rojo"></div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12 rosa"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 naranja"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 naranja"></div>
   <div class="col-md-2 col-md-4 col-xs-6 azul"></div>
   <div class="col-md-2 col-md-4 col-xs-6 azul"></div>
   <div class="col-md-4 col-md-4 col-xs-6 azul"></div>
   <div class="col-md-2 col-md-4 col-xs-6 azul"></div>
   <div class="col-md-2 col-md-4 col-xs-6 azul"></div>
   <div class="col-md-2 col-md-4 col-xs-6 azul"></div>
   <div class="col-md-2 col-md-4 col-xs-6 azul"></div>
   <div class="col-md-4 col-md-4 col-xs-6 azul"></div>
   <div class="col-md-2 col-md-4 col-xs-6 azul"></div>
   <div class="col-md-2 col-md-4 col-xs-6 azul"></div>
  </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 verde"></div>
</div>
```